# What is the expected number of extreme points in a set of points drawn from a normal distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Say I construct a set of points $S$ by drawing $k$ points from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ independently from say a gaussian distribution*. I am wondering how the expected size of the set $E$ consisting of the *extreme points* of $S$ grows as a function of $k$?

I am not sure I am using the right terminology here, but by *extreme points* I mean the points in $S$ that are *on* the edge of the convex hull of $S$. I.e., if we imagine a rubber band around the convex hull of $S$, $E$ are the points of $S$ touching this rubber band. I hope that make sense.

Anyway, my intuition is that the expected size of $E$ only grows very slowly in $k$, say something like $O(\log(k))$. Does anyone know if that is actually the case?

*I am trying to reason about some naturally occuring data, essentially the points are lumped together around some *mean* point, so a gaussian seems a natural approximation.

Comment: The case $n=2$, $k=4$ is treated in this paper:   https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Blatter_4shots.pdf

Comment: Thanks I will have a look. However, what I am actually interesting in is how the size of $E$ grows as a function of $k$ (for fixed values of $d$). I have edited the question to say so.